# When converting from decimal to hexadecimal, how do I retain the leading zeros at the beginning? c++

Tags: c++, string, hex, converters

If I were to enter -4094, my output would be following.

```
[Hexadecimal:   fffff002]
```

I am trying to keep the leading zeros for my hexadecimal output. By leading zeros, I mean the extra 'f' characters on the left of my output.
My result should be the following.

```
[Hexadecimal:   fffffffffffff002]
```

How can I accomplish this?

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>     //Header needed for input/output operations
#include <iomanip>      //Header needed for hexadecimal output
#include <sstream>      //Header needed for stringstream type
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 int num;   
cout << "Please enter number to convert: ";
cin >> num;
 stringstream ss;
 ss << hex << (num);
 string res(ss.str());
 cout << " [Hexadecimal:   " << res << "]\n\n";

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fffffffffffff002` where are leading zeros in the desired output?

Comment: It does seem odd that the question and desired output do not seem to be in agreement with each other. The answer to the headline is to use strings. I would also recommend proper indentation, and not making "what" comments but "why" comments.

Comment: Try using `std::fill('0')` before printing your hexadecimal number; also use `setw`.

Comment: On your compiler, `int` is 32 bits wide. If you need a 64-bit value, you must cast it: `ss << hex << static_cast<int64_t>(num);` Or just define `num` as `int64_t` to begin with.

Comment: @273K I apologize for the confusion. My professor refers to the extra 'f's at the beginning as leading zeros. To be more specific, what can I do to my code to be able to reproduce the extra character that come at the beginning of the hexadecimal conversion?

Comment: They are _not_ zeroes. Please return your professor for a warranty replacement.

Comment: It appears an `int` on your platform is 32-bits.  Recompile your operating system so an `int` is 64-bits.

Comment: Your `int` is 32 bits. `fffff002` is 32 bits (each hexadecimal digit corresponds to four binary digits). `fffffffffffff002` is 64 bits. This means that you need a 64-bit integer instead.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the question, the goal is to print a given positive or negative integer as a hexadecimal number with a fixed width.

The solution is to use the appropriate manipulators before printing the number on the stringstream. In addition to `std::hex`, `std::setw` can be used to set the desired width and `std::setfill` can be used to set the "filling" character. In this case, we would want `0` for positive numbers and `f` for negative numbers.

All in all:

```
#include <iostream>     //Header needed for input/output operations
#include <iomanip>      //Header needed for hexadecimal output
#include <sstream>      //Header needed for stringstream type

int main()
{
    int w = 8; // Number of digits to print
    int num;   
    std::cout << "Please enter number to convert: ";
    std::cin >> num;
    std::stringstream ss;
    char fill = (num < 0) ? 'f' : '0';  // Extend with 'f' for negative numbers and '0' for positive numbers
    ss << std::hex << std::setw(w) << std::setfill(fill) << (num);
    std::string res(ss.str());
    std::cout << " [Hexadecimal:   " << res << "]\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```